# Точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке DLL

Tags: qtcreator

Не могу запустить собранный файл вне Qt.
Из qt creator запускается нормально. Программа создана как проект qt "Приложение на языке C++". Версия Qt Creator 4.0.2.

При запуске из проводника вылазит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папку с запускаемым ехе-файлом нужно подкинуть все недостающие библиотеки. Каких библиотек не хватает можно посмотреть с помощью lister'a Total Commander'a. Выбрать исполняемый файл и нажать F3, появится что-то похожее на это [image: окно Lister'a] 
Те библиотеки, что выделены красным значком необходимо скопировать в папку и ехе-файлом.